# Simple MVT question involving roots of even degree three term polynomial

Tags: calculus

Showing $x^{2k}+px+q$ has at most 2 roots $(k\in \mathbb{N})$,

So far I have assumed that there exists three roots $x_1<x_2<x_3$

which then by Rolle's theorem implies  $\exists \ c_1\in (x_1,x_2)$ and $c_2 \in (x_2,x_3)$ such that $f^{\prime}(c_1)=f^{\prime}(c_2)=0$ which further implies that $\exists \ \zeta \in (c_1,c_2)$ such that $f^{\prime\prime}(\zeta)=0$ which implies $\zeta = 0$ since $f^{\prime\prime}(\zeta)=2k(2k-1)x^{2(k-1)}$

$\zeta = 0$ implies further that $ c_1 < 0 < c_2 $ and that

$f^{\prime}(c-1)=2kc_{1}^{2k-1}+p<p<2kc_{2}^{2k-1}+p = f^{\prime}(c_2)$ yet we know that $f^{\prime}(c_1)=f^{\prime}(c_2)=0$ which should imply that $p=0$ , $f^{\prime}$ can only have one root since single term and thus the polynomial doesn't have three roots...

am I doing it right? it just doesn't feel concrete. Somehow I feel like I should be showing $f^{\prime}=0$ everywhere yet it doesn't seem like this does the trick, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The question can be reformulated as showing the the number of intersections of the curve $y=x^{2k}$ with the line $y=-px-q$ is at most 2.

One can try to show at most one intersection on either side of the $y$-axis.

The second is a linear function (fixed derivative) and the first is not only increasing its derivative is also increasing for positive $x$. SO after any  intersection to make another intersection the graph should come down which is not possible as derivative keeps increasing.

You can use similar argument with decreasing derivative for $x<0$.

Comment: So does this mean my previous method was incorrect? This does seem much simpler.

Comment: Your method is correct. I also use derivative argument to show why the curve cannot come down again. The given function has a neat splitting  as $y=x^{2k}$ and a linear function which are individually easy to deal with. Hence this ends up being simple.

Comment: One might use the term "convex function" for $x^{2k}$ or for the full function..

Comment: @LutzL You are right. This example could be one possible way of introducing convex functions.